# how to compute $\frac{\partial L_{total}}{\partial \overrightarrow{x}}$ in Neural Style Transfer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am reading the paper "[Image Style Transfer Using Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Gatys_Image_Style_Transfer_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf)". Another paper is [A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576).

I cannot understand part of Fig2 in this paper. The Fig2 is in the following:
[image]

I have some questions about the middle part: compute its derivative with respect to the pixel values by error back-propagation.

1, what does $\frac{\partial E_{L}}{\partial F^{L-1}}$ mean in the top-middle part of this figure? How to compute it?

2, How to compute $\frac{\partial L_{total}}{\partial\overrightarrow{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial E_{L}}{\partial\overrightarrow{x}}$ by back propagation?

I guess, $\frac{\partial E_{L}}{\partial\overrightarrow{x}}$=$\frac{\partial E_{L}}{\partial F^{L}}\frac{\partial F^{L}}{\partial F^{L-1}}...\frac{\partial F^{1}}{\partial \overrightarrow{x}}$. And $\frac{\partial F^{l}}{\partial F^{l-1}}$, where $l = 0, 1, ..., L$ is computed by back propagation. Am I right?

3, what are computed by back propagation. I looked into back propagation, but have no idea how back propagation is working in these two papers.

Could someone give more details and explanations? Thanks